# How to find the expected value of a random variable when it is observed only in a range?

Tags: censoring

I want to estimate an average livespan of a user account which is a time-difference in days between the account open and account closed. I observe the livespan of accounts that were closed before the current date when I do my analysis but some accounts are still open and I do not know when they are to be closed. I observe all the history between the time when we launched our service and the current date. Accounts might be opened at any day in this range not necessarily at time zero.

In the answer, please suggest any reasonable parametric family of distributions that are applicable in this case.